# Update SQL table using Vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-update, sqlcommand

I have a VB.net script that needs to put information into a table in the database. The catch is that it is based off of an item Id, so when I am updating I cannot just insert the row  would like to update the row if it is already there. For this I need to use the Update command like so:

```
mysqlCommand = New SQLCommand(UPDATE tableName Colum2=Newvalue ... Where Column1=ItemId)
```

However I am wondering if there is anyway to tell wether or not a line was updated when I run

```
mysqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

so that I do not need to check before I run this command and switch between this update command and a INSERT INTO command

Answer (score 1):

From documentation of [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected.

So you can write like this:

```vb
Dim recordsAffected As Integer = mysqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
If recordsAffected = 1 Then 'it worked
```

**EDIT:** Regarding @macoms01 answer, my original intention was to have something like this:

```vb
Select Case recordsAffected
  Case 0: 'it did not work
  Case 1: 'it worked
  Case Else: Throw New BadDataException
End Select
```

You can never be sure that unique constraints are set on the DB - expect bad data.

But then I thought it would probably be too complicated for its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Neolisk, but a slight improvement could be to use the following:

```
Dim recordsAffected As Integer = mysqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
If recordsAffected > 0 Then 'it worked
```

or this:

```
Dim recordsAffected As Integer = mysqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
If recordsAffected >= 1 Then 'it worked
```

@Neolisk's code will work great as long as Column1 is a unique identifier.  Otherwise you may be updating more than one row.  The "greater than"/"greater than or equal to" operator will catch the scenario where you are updating more than one row.

Comment: +1. Thanks for your comment. I updated my answer, hope it looks better now.

Comment: @Neolisk - I assumed that's what you were going for.  Just wanted to point it out for DoNotArrestMe in case he wasn't aware. I "upvoted" your answer as well since you were the original "responder".